# Is there a Hotmail adapter for Outlook 2011 on Mac?

Tags: macos, email, microsoft-outlook, hotmail

Ironically, the only email account I have that does not run on the new Outlook 2011 for Mac is my MSN account.  I have to run it in Mac Mail which autoconfigures the account without a problem, whereas Outlook 2011 does not.  It seems that there is no connector unless you are running a PC.

Does anyone know if there is a Hotmail/MSN connector for Outlook 2011 (on Mac) available anywhere, or if there is a workaround available?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to configure the account manually for hotmail?

http://www.ghacks.net/2009/03/14/hotmail-pop3-configuration/

Comment: yes I tried to manually configure but this is an MSN Windows Live account and requires the Outlook adapter from Microsoft which works 100% on my PC on XP Pro with Office 2007 but not on Mac with Office 2011.  I think this is another case of Microsoft doing as little as possible for Mac users as slow as possible

Comment: You did say Hotmail?

Answer (score 1):

I actually have my msn and my hotmail account setup with Outlook 2011 for Mac. However, it works as a POP3 account which sucks. here is the step by step http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2352963

I'm trying to set it up as in my iPhone which it would work as an Exchange account but I haven't been able to... I will report when I can.

well, it really sucks, I try to go around but it's not trivial. MS needs to work on activating a connector or Exchange ActiveSync to work... POP 3 is soooo 80's.

in case you are interested on the iPhone setup here... http://www.iphonedownloadblog.com/2010/08/30/hotmail-iphone/  it works on iPad too